Set docker build options (like --platform) with testcontainers
I'm trying to set the docker build option --platform linux/amd64 (when running on Apple Silicon)
I tried...
new GenericContainer<>("someImage")
    .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(it -> it.withPlatform("linux/amd64"));

unfortunately it does not run on Apple Silicon, however the equivalent command works:
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t someLabel .

